# How can I populate a global JavaScript object using data from JSP?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I need to maintain some data client side for form validation. The data is created server-side, and then my plan is to keep it in a global JavaScript object so that it can be accessed by other functions as needed.

My code currently looks something like this :

```
<html>
<body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.globVal = new Object();
<%
    SomeObject o = new SomeObject();
    ArrayList a = o.getArrayList();
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
        String str = a.get(i);


%>
         window.globVal[<%= str %>] = <%= o.retrieve(str) %>;
    <%}%>
    </script>

...
[SOME OTHER STUFF]
....
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function myFunc(){
        alert("My global obj: " +window.globVal);
    }
    </html>
```

The alert prints out "My global obj: undefined

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: globalVal = new Array(); how about this ?

Comment: Is the problem that the script is not being run at all?

Comment: You are showing us some Java and saying that the JavaScript doesn't do what you want. The first thing you should do is to determine if the Java is generating the JavaScript you expect or if the JavaScript you expect does not work. Then narrow the scope of the question to either "This Java fails to generate this JavaScript" or "This JavaScript fails to have this result in the browser".

Answer (score -1):

I would create the object/array in Java, serialize it to JSON using a JSON encoder, bind the JSON String to a request parameter, and initialize the JavaScript object from this JSON string:

```
<script>
    window.globVal = ${theJsonString};
</script>
```

Comment: Why express it as a JavaScript string and then immediately pass it to JSON.parse? Just `window.globVal = '${theJsonString}`.

Comment: That is probably a nicer way of doing it, but does not solve the problem of the Array/ Object not being visibile

Comment: Remove everything from your first script except `window.globVal = "test";`, and see if it displays test in your function. If it does, try to replace "test" with `${theJsonString}`, and I don't see how it could fail. If it doesn't, then I have no idea.

Comment: Thanks for the tip of testing to see if the variable was visible and then going from there